# Visual Studio test V2 not distributing tests on Multiple agents - TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have tfs 2018: I want to run My 10 thousand tests on 5 agents distributedly/Parallel:

What I have done:

Created a release definition where in Agent phase, Selected `EXECUTE ON MULTIPLE AGENTS` and given 5 Agents as MAXIMUM Number of agents.

Then created a Visual Studio test V2 and Selected `RUN TESTS IN PARALLEL ON MULTICORE MACHINE`.

When I release the definition, It Created 5 tabs:

```
Agent 1 of 5
Agent 2 of 5
Agent 3 of 5
Agent 4 of 5
Agent 5 of 5
```

What the system is doing:
It is using a single agent (Agent machine) and Executing all tests on the single machine in five phases one by one.

Question:

Why the tests are not distributing and executing on 5 different agents even they are online and selected.
Why is it executing with single agent and replicating all tests? and dicing this replication into 5 phases. in all five phases, same agent is being used.

Comment: I couldn't get your point.
You want me to go into code and distribute test for each agent or you want to tell some configurations which automatically distribute tests across agents ?

Comment: In the VS Test task, under "Advanced Execution Options", what do your settings look like?

Comment: Batch tests: based on no of tests and agents , Automatically determine the batch size, this is under advanced options.

Comment: Do you actually have 5 concurrent pipelines? They have to either be purchased or licensed through users with Visual Studio Enterprise MSDN licenses being assigned to the account.

Comment: I have a single pipeline set as a single build definition which compiles the code and single release definition which run the tests on that code.This is all managed by a single agent pool which have 5 agent(5 machines) where i want to run tests distributedly/simultaneously. What else i need here?  Why are you asking to purchase enterprize liscence? what does it mean?

Comment: Have you configured  default test configuration for project collection, take a look at this thread:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/161220/vstest-version-2-task-not-distributing-tests.html  if you are meeting the same issue.